# pytest: If a crash/segfault/etc. occurs during testing, is there a way to make pytest log the crash as a test failure and continue testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have a few unit tests written using pytest that have successfully caused segfaults to occur. However if a segfault occurs (on my Mac) during these execution, pytest seems to quit altogether and provide no information on what caused the python interpreter to crash.

Now I could infer from the logs the specific test that was crashing and determine the values used within, but I was wondering if there was any way to be able to somehow log the crash as a regular test failure and keep iterating through my tests without stopping?

If helpful, I can try to conceive an example but I think the question should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: `py.test` is also running in Python, so if the interpreter crashes entirely so does the testing; there's no Python exception to catch and you will have to debug that at the OS level.

Comment: And where does one begin to look for that? The py.test log in my case shows the last thing to be done was executing a command that does not result in any crashes, so there's something else happening that pytest cannot see.

Answer (score 5):

Using the pytest-xdist plugin it will restart the nodes automatically when they crash, so installing the plugin and running the tests with `-n1` should make py.test survive the crashing tests.